# how to make public IP works on ec2 machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

public IP is not working on ec2 machine

I am creating simple ec2 machine but my public IP address is not working. In security group inbound rules i have allowed all to ssh and http. I can login to my ec2 machine via gitbash but not sure what else i can do to make public IP work

Comment: Please explain what it would mean for it to "work" exactly. Your login via gitbash is using the public IP address to access the server over SSH. What more do you expect to work?

Comment: I am trying to load a webpage via public IP

Comment: So do you have any web server software installed and running on the EC2 server? You haven't mentioned anything about actually setting up a web site on the server in your question.

Comment: I have just used default settings while launching ec2 machine, no i have not installed any web server

Comment: its saying 'refused to connect'

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, my ssh works fine but when I try to connect using my Public DNS, it says"connection refused"

Comment: If you just used default settings for your EC2 server, then it is just a virtual machine running the Linux operating system. There is no web server running on that by default. Your public IP address is already "working". Your HTTP requests are getting "refused to connect" because the server has no web server processes running, listening on the HTTP port `80`.

Comment: If you are not having a webserver running on this EC2, what are trying to connect to then? By default web server is not installed in EC2. What is your AMI ? Is it Amazon linux?

Comment: yes its amazon linux

Comment: now its showing This site can’t be reached took too long to respond. I have installed apache2 webserver already

Comment: Is the webserver running? Check from the SSH console using `curl -lv http://localhost`

Comment: Failed to connect to localhost port 80 after 0 ms: Connection refused

Comment: i tried with ubuntu this time

Comment: Then service is not running. Try `systemctl start httpd` . Add sudo if required.

Comment: apache2 is actively running now but still having same issue

Comment: Looks like apache2 comes with a different one too. Look at the link https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/star-stop-restart-apache2-webserver/ which could help in basic checks

Answer (score -1):

For starting up a webserver with instance launch, you can use [**user-data**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-console) as below (Eg: for Amazon Linux AMI):

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
yum install -y httpd
systemctl start httpd
systemctl enable httpd
usermod -a -G apache ec2-user
chown -R ec2-user:apache /var/www
chmod 2775 /var/www
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \;
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} \;
cd /var/www/html
echo "<html><body><p><b>Hello from EC2</b></p></body></html>" >> index.html
```

Do note that for the above to work, the instance will need internet access when it launches. This can be via direct public IP association (i.e. Subnet setting) or options like NAT Gateway etc.

Comment: I am using default VPC, do i still need that?

Comment: Yeah. It doesn't matter whether it is default vpc or a user-created one. EC2 instance launch usually comes without a webserver installed unless you are launching an AMI from a Marketplace which might have a webserver already packaged with it.

Comment: i have already installed apache2 successfully but still same issue

Comment: I am using default vpc and default subnet, so internet connection should be there

Comment: Installation should be followed by starting the command. If you have used `sudo yum install httpd` in Amazon Linux, follow by `sudo systemctl start httpd` to start it. After this check using `curl -lv localhost` .

Comment: yes it shows connected to port 80

Comment: Thats good. You server is now up. You might see a default response of `403` which is fine. You can put a custom `index.html` in the root directory by following as below:

`sudo su`

`cd /var/www/html`

`echo "<html><body><p><b>Test Success</b></p></body></html>" >> index.html`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help halod, but I am not sure how i can do that. I am new to this field

Comment: @jagroop no worries mate. Since you got the message of *connected to port 80*, your server is up. Can you try to access http://x.x.x.x which is the public IP of your instance to see whether it is loading the default apache page. Do note that it should be **http** and not **https**

Comment: yes it works, OMG  it took me 2 days to figure out this.  Thanks alot for your precious time and help. feel blessed to be part of this community